# Datatables - RTL support

Tags: jquery, datatables, right-to-left

I am using Datatables plugin version **1.10.1**

I can't seem to find any support for RTL languages.
The translation options are fine, but they only change the text. The layout and direction of the elements still remain LTR.

Is there a built in option that I overlooked ?
It would be great if someone could shed some light on the subject (and maybe provide a decent RTL css).

(I am using bootstrap, and included dataTables.bootstrap.css, in case it matters)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,
You can try surround your datatable with some RTL paragraph :

```
<p dir="RTL">put Datatables  here</p>
```

Or change datatable div to be RTL :

```
<div id="Datatables" dir="RLT"/>
```

Or use RTL on you html page:

```
 <html lang="en" dir="RTL">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [bootstrap RTL](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl) it provides simple yet robust right-to-left capability for Bootstrap 3, by employing new theming feature of it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply `direction:rtl` to the whole **table container**. say, make sure to set the `fixedColumns: true` in Datatable's setting arguments. So, then you may need to make your table scrollable:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yourTable').DataTable( {
    scrollY:        300,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    fixedColumns:   true
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
    direction: rtl;
    width: 800px;
}
th, td{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```